# Juju Icehouse-Openstack LXC

Tags: juju, openstack, lxc

Trying to instantiate an LXC image on a compute node, by changing `virt-type (string)` field, under nova-compute charm to `lxc`. This, however, does not update the virt_type, in `nova-compute.conf` file.

Furthermore, by manually updating `compute_driver=nova.virt.lxc.LXCDriver`, I get the following error log:

- http://paste.ubuntu.com/7728899/.

Setting  `virt_type=lxc` and `compute_driver=libvirt.LibvirtDrive`, gives this error log:

- http://paste.ubuntu.com/7729006/

As noted, I've installed lxc and nova-compute-lxc. Any thoughts?

Commenting out line 5907 in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py`, while virt_type=lxc, gets rid of virConnectBaselineCPU error.

Upon restarting nova-compute, the following log is obtained:

- http://paste.ubuntu.com/7738267/, which seems to imply that you are on your own! At any rate, launching an image from Dashboard fails during mounting of container's file system, with the following log:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7738278/

Answer (score 0):

You currently can't run nova-compute in LXC, this is a known limitation and we're working to solve that for 14.10/juno.