# Openstack Juno Juju Charms for Utopic

Tags: juju, maas, 14.10, openstack

Finally, managed to deploy a utopic image, see [MAAS 1.7 How to Deploy utopic images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551085/maas-1-7-how-to-deploy-utopic-images); however, my problem now is that I can't deploy  utopic charms:

```
$ juju status
environment: maas17
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.20.11
    dns-name: utopic.maas17
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-b61e1cb4-7112-11e4-aede-08002781ac14/
    series: utopic
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=490M
    state-server-member-status: has-vote

$ juju deploy --to 0 juju-gui -v --debug
2014-11-21 03:07:48 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:37 running juju [1.20.11-utopic-amd64 gc]
2014-11-21 03:07:48 DEBUG juju.conn api.go:187 trying cached API connection settings
2014-11-21 03:07:48 INFO juju.conn api.go:270 connecting to API addresses: [10.0.0.70:17070 utopic.maas17:17070 utopic.maas17:17070]
2014-11-21 03:07:48 INFO juju.state.api apiclient.go:242 dialing "wss://10.0.0.70:17070/environment/31846f9e-c1b4-4490-842d-2f5d11f49e7f/api"
2014-11-21 03:07:48 INFO juju.state.api apiclient.go:176 connection established to "wss://10.0.0.70:17070/environment/31846f9e-c1b4-4490-842d-2f5d11f49e7f/api"
2014-11-21 03:07:49 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:323 charm not found: cs:utopic/juju-gui
```

If I deploy Trusty charms, would I be able to deploy Openstack Juno or would it default to Icehouse? (Specifically, I am interested in deploying LXCs, which is currently not possible with Icehouse.)
Cheers,

Edit 1: Scratch using Trusty charms:

```
$ juju deploy --to 0 trusty/juju-gui -v --debug
2014-11-21 03:27:09 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:37 running juju [1.20.11-utopic-amd64 gc]
2014-11-21 03:27:09 DEBUG juju.conn api.go:187 trying cached API connection settings
2014-11-21 03:27:09 INFO juju.conn api.go:270 connecting to API addresses: [10.0.0.70:17070 utopic.maas17:17070 utopic.maas17:17070]
2014-11-21 03:27:09 INFO juju.state.api apiclient.go:242 dialing "wss://10.0.0.70:17070/environment/31846f9e-c1b4-4490-842d-2f5d11f49e7f/api"
2014-11-21 03:27:09 INFO juju.state.api apiclient.go:176 connection established to "wss://10.0.0.70:17070/environment/31846f9e-c1b4-4490-842d-2f5d11f49e7f/api"
2014-11-21 03:27:24 INFO juju.cmd cmd.go:113 Added charm "cs:trusty/juju-gui-15" to the environment.
2014-11-21 03:27:25 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:323 cannot assign unit "juju-gui/0" to machine 0: series does not match
```

Answer (score 0):

Most charms are being written for the LTS releases which you can see at http://manage.jujucharms.com/charms/trusty, versus what's available for Utopic (http://manage.jujucharms.com/charms/utopic). But that doesn't mean you can't install Juju on Utopic and still deploy OpenStack Juno charms once available. They will just be deployed on Trusty machines.

Comment: To clarify then, 1- There is no need to upgrade to 14.10 in order to deploy Juno? 2- Current Trusty charms are capable of deploying Juno, addressing issues such as http://askubuntu.com/questions/490164/juju-icehouse-openstack-lxc?

Comment: @user281985 1st A) Nope, Juno charms work fine on Trusty (14.04), 2nd A) im not quite sure on the status of nova-compute-lxc but https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OpenStack/LXC seems to indicate that someone has got it working in 14.04, You may want to open a bug against the nova package and add your error logs detailing your issue with nova-compute-lxc

Comment: Verified 1, as per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseNotes/OpenStackCharms, the critical qualifier is " openstack-origin: cloud:trusty-juno"