# Can I deploy to LXC in a Juno/trusty environment?

Tags: 14.04, juju, openstack, lxc

This is a follow up on [Juju Icehouse-Openstack LXC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490164/juju-icehouse-openstack-lxc). It seems that Trusty and Juno combo also do not allow LXC instantiation, i.e., Changing "virt-type" in nova-compute charm does not change compute_virt field, in nova.conf.

Furthermore, changing this field manually, per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OpenStack/LXC, does not seem to have any effect either. As there are various problems with Utopic images, e.g., [Openstack Juno Juju Charms for Utopic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/552062/openstack-juno-juju-charms-for-utopic) and [MAAS 1.7 How to Deploy utopic images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551085/maas-1-7-how-to-deploy-utopic-images), I am wondering if there is any method available to deploy LXC in Juno-Trusty environment?
Cheers,